# HttpLoggingInterceptor interfering with with refresh token mechanism

Tags: android, okhttp, interceptor

I am facing a very strange issue in my Android app with `OkHttp3` `Interceptor` where I set different logging levels to different build variants.

I have setup an `OkHttp3` `Interceptor` in my app to intercept API requests, and if any API returns `401` error, the interceptor gets the refreshed token from backend and updates the header of original request with the new token and repeats it. Let's call this **RefreshTokenInterceptor**. I add this interceptor when building my `OKHttpClient`. Besides this, I also add an `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to log the API requests and responses or stop logging in case of release builds. Let's call this **LoggingInterceptor**

Here is the code where I build my `OkHttpClient`. This code should be enough because the refresh mechanism works fine if the logging level is changed.

```
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

// changing level to Level.BODY in the below solves the issue,
// but I don't want to log the results
when {
        BuildConfig.DEBUG -> loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        else -> loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
}

val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .addInterceptor(ConnectivityInterceptor())
      .addInterceptor(TokenRefreshInterceptor())
      .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
      .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

When I set the logging level of the **LoggingInterceptor** in both cases to `Level.BODY`, everything works fine. But in case of logging level set to `Level.NONE`, the token refresh mechanism stops working.

To be more specific, in this case, this is what happens in **RefreshTokenInterceptor**: when a request returns 401, the refresh call is made, but nothing happens afterwards. No success or failure case gets called (Maybe the interceptor `Chain` breaks but who knows).

Here is what I have tried so far

- Removing the **LoggingInterceptor** altogether -> does not work
- Setting logging level to `Level.NONE` for all build variants -> does
  not work
- Setting logging level to `Level.BODY` for all build variants -> works
  like magic

I also searched a lot today on this, but could not find any link between logging levels messing up other interceptors. Any help would be appreciated, and if you need more code, I can post it.

Comment: Could you try adding loggingInterceptor first before TokenRefreshInterceptor? not sure but it might have something to do with the request/response chaining. Also, can you post your TokenRefreshInterceptor code?

Comment: Actually the problem was being caused by a memory leak in the RefreshTokenInterceptor which was created by OkHttp3 Response object which was not closed. When I closes it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was being caused by a memory leak which happened because an `OkHttp3` `Response` object in the `TokenRefreshInterceptor` which was not being closed. I got to know about this leak on `Firebase Console`. Closing this `Response` after consuming it solved the issue. But I'm still unsure why it worked fine when I enabled body-level logging.

Comment: You need to release resources held by the previous response body when you use chain.proceed to try another request. Calling close() is the best and safest way to do this. Reading the entire body also releases those resources, which is why the interceptor prevented the crash.

Comment: Oh this makes total sense. Thank you so much :)